# Pandas column with dot notation referring to index during apply

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any special reference for `.name` in pandas?

I am using the below code to do combine to columns, but the `x.name` is referencing to index instead of the column values

```
df.apply(lambda x: f"{x.name}.{x.mime_name}", axis=1).head()
```

The same works if if use `x['name']` instead

```
df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['name']}.{x.mime_name}", axis=1).head()
```

[image: screenshot]

I have not set the name attribute on the dataframe and is a fresh dataframe (i restarted the kernel and checked too). Below is the df creation code

`file_list` is list of dictionaries

```
df = pd.DataFrame(file_list)
df = df.set_index('id')
df['mime_name'] = df.mimeType.map(mime_mapper)
df['local_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x.name}.{x.mime_name}", axis=1)
```

Comment: pd.Series does already have a `name` attribute, therefore using the dot notation with 'name' is ill-advised.  Note:  `dir(pd.Series())`, 'name' already exists.  I highly recommending using df['name'] at all times the dot notation has limits.

Comment: ah, so thats the reason its acting wierd, thanks :)

Comment: can you put that as answer, so i can mark as completed?

Comment: This is a good example of why you shouldn't use `.`/dot/attribute style access for columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Series` does already have a name attribute, therefore using the dot notation with 'name' is ill-advised.

***Note:*** `dir(pd.Series())`, 'name' already exists. I highly recommending using df['column name'] at all times the dot notation has limits.